# Loading css and scripts via import in component's css vs linking it in index

Tags: angular

What difference does it make apart from global vs local when you put css in index.html vs component's css file because I a trying to setup a theme in angular. When I put the styles and script in index file everything works correctly but when i import it from the components css and ts file then the menu toggle stops working and some css seems broken and I need to put it in components css and ts because I dont want it to load on other pages.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/dashboard/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/dashboard/dist/css/skins/_all- skins.min.css">
    </head>
    <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<app-root></app-root>
  <script src="assets/dashboard/js/adminlte.js"></script>
</body
```

Components css file

```
 @import url('../../assets/dashboard/css/AdminLTE.min.css');
    @import url('../../assets/dashboard/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css');
```

Components ts file

```
import'../../assets/dashboard/js/adminlte.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

The css in the component css file only works for the html of the component (template) and does not work for others components.
You should use link in index.html for your global css and use the component css for specific style of the component.

Edit : You can style children components with `::ng-deep` but avoid it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

When you include styles and scripts in index.html, Browser DOM rendering with get blocked until CSS and Scripts are parsed successfully. This will make sure app component will be rendered only after Styles and Scripts loaded.

When you import in component specific scss, it will be loaded specific to that component, Also it may be loaded after Component rendered in DOM. We need to make DOM Component render only after Script & styles loaded successfully.